ImportError: No module named cx_Oracle
I am getting ImportError: No module named cx_Oracle error when calling test.py from call_test.py. If I execute test.py directly, it works fine.
Below is the code:
db_connection.py
import cx_Oracle 
from configparser import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser()
config.read('config_dev.ini')
db_config = config['database']

dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn(db_config['host'], db_config['port'], service_name=db_config['service_name'])
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user=db_config['username'], password=db_config['password'], dsn=dsn)

test.py
import db_connection as db

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cursor = db.connection.cursor()
    querystring = "select * from dual"
    cursor.execute(querystring)
    res = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in res:
        print(row) 

call_test.py
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["python", "test.py"])


You should use the latest version of the driver: it got renamed to python-oracledb a couple of years ago.  see the release announcement.
python -m pip install oracledb --user

And then make db_connection.py like this:
import oracledb
from configparser import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser()
config.read('config_dev.ini')
db_config = config['database']

connection = oracledb.connect(user=db_config['username'], password=db_config['password'], 
                              host=db_config['host'], port=db_config['port'],
                              service_name=db_config['service_name'])


The documentation is all at https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Try to install the module:
pip install cx_oracle


Technically correct, but new users should start with python-oracledb, not the old cx_Oracle driver.

I didn't get which version the user was using ... did you ?

Any version of cx_Oracle is at least two years old.  The last release in this namespace was in November 2021.
